# Laravel 4.2 Eloquent create: Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel `4.2.*` I have a `User` Model where `insert()` method is working normally but when I'm using `create()` method it is throwing an error:

> Array to string conversion

My model:

```
class User extends Eloquent{

    public $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'created_by'];

    public function insertUserInfo($data)
    {
        //return self::insert($data); //working with no error but not adding `created_at`
        return self::create($data); //Array to string conversion
    }
}
```

Sample data:

```
$data = [
    'first_name' => 'Jhon',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'created_by' => Auth::id() // var_dump(Auth::id()) => int(11)
];
```

It 'll be helpful if anyone can help me as why `create()` is throwing an error.

PHP `v5.6.3`

***EDITED***
I can assure that there is no array value inside `$data`. and the same `$data` is working with `insert()` but throwing error when using `create()` or `save()` method.

Comment: `var_dump($data)` maybe something isn't what you think it should be.

Comment: @aynber: Ya I have checked that but but all the fields are as expected, moreover same dataset is working with `insert` method.

Comment: Maybe `Auth::id()` is returning an array ...

Comment: @NetGuy: var_dump(Auth::id()) => int(11).

Comment: Why don't you use `$user = new User($data);` then `$user->save();`

Comment: good question @NetGuy, `create` auto add `DATETIME` to `created_at`. will test `save()`.

Comment: @RaunakGupta Did it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135793/discussion-between-raunak-gupta-and-net-guy).

Comment: as this is just a wrapper for `create` method it's a bit pointless. but have you tried changeing `insertUserInfo` into a static method?

Comment: @NetGuy: same issue with `save()`; *'Array to string conversion'*

Comment: @Mei: try that with no luck.

Comment: @RaunakGupta try `var_dump($data)` one of your values is an array.

Comment: @Mei: I can assure you that there is no array value inside `$data`. and the same `$data` is working with `insert()` but throwing error when using `create()` or `save()` method.

Comment: Then you need to open Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model and dump from the original create method to see what's happening

Comment: @RaunakGupta did you solve this?

Comment: @SanzeebAryal: no I did't able to solve this, so right now I'm using `insert()` method and manually saving `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `array` type hinting:

```
 public function insertUserInfo(array $data)
 {
    return self::create($data);
 }
```

Comment: tried this, but with success, still getting an error.